# Grease pencil fill appears infront of glass, while in 3d space it is behind

Tags: blend-modes, grease-pencil

Trying to put a grease pencil layer behind and infront of a glass jar in Blender 2.8. But the part behind the jar appears to be infront of the jar. Is there some kind of Blend mode in grease pencil I can change?[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is it the same after rendering ?
What do you mean by 2 grease pencil ? are those strokes in the same object ? layer ? if not, did you try to put them in the same object and arrange the layer priority or stroke placement ?
I just Tried with a normal object with and without glass or transparent shader and it worked normally..

Comment: I am using Blender 2.8, I should have mentioned to begin with. I didn't say "2 grease pencil" so I'm not sure exactly what your asking. But I have a grease pencil layer behind the glass jar, and a grease pencil layer in-front of the glass jar. The 2 grease pencil layers are separate objects.  It appears if I use the glass bsdf shader in cycles it works, and I could play with that. But I was using Blend modes in eevee to fake the glass, and once rendered it doesn't appear to work in eevee.